# how to select max in List<> using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq first time and i get a problem. The problem is that i want to get the Random 20 value from table on condition. And my condition is 
Get the maximum value where `PercentageValue <= 0.5 && PercentageValue >= 90`
Get the Minimum Value where `PercentageValue <= 0.5 && PercentageValue >= 90`
My problem is how to get the value if i use .Max() it will return only one value but if you show the table value 0.5 is more than once.
What i want :- i want that first i get the List<> of maximum value then List<> of minimum value then i get the random value from this list.

**My table settings with data is below :**

```
ID  ImageName         PercentValue
1   0.5%A (0.4).png     0.5
2   0.5%B (0.5).png     0.5
3   0.5%C (0.4).png     0.5
4   0.5%D (0.4).png     0.5
5   0.5%E (0.4).png     0.5
6   0.5%F (0.4).png     0.5
7   1%A (0.9).png       1
8   1%B (0.9).png       1
9   1%C (1.1).png       1
10  1%D (1.1).png       1
11  1%E (0.9).png       0.9
12  1%F (1.0).png       1
13  10%A1 (9.5).png     10
14  12%A1 (12.1).png    12
15  15%A1 (15.4).png    15
16  15%A2 (13.7).png    15
17  20%A1 (19.9).png    20   
18  21%.png             92
19  derr.png            94
```

my code

```
var intMax = db.ImageSettings.Max(r => r.PercentageValue <= 0.5 && r.PercentageValue >= 90);

 var listMin = db.ImageSettings.Min(r => r.PercentageValue <= 0.5 && r.PercentageValue >= 90);
```

Comment: Btw, `PercentageValue <= 0.5 && PercentageValue >= 90` is always `false`

Comment: condition itself is wrong .check with .5 greater and less than 90
and then put where and get the list

Comment: This could be identified by using the rubber duck debugging!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This

```
var Max = collection.Where(x => x.Percentvalue == collection.Where(a=>a.Percentvalue>=0.5 && a.Percentvalue<=90 ).Max(y => y.Percentvalue));
var Min = collection.Where(x => x.Percentvalue == collection.Where(a=>a.Percentvalue>=0.5 && a.Percentvalue<=90 ).Min(y => y.Percentvalue));
```

Comment: does the condition `a.Percentvalue<=0.5 && a.Percentvalue>=90` can be true at any time?

Comment: Yes it will return max value with matched condition and then list will sort all  collection those having that max value

Comment: i am talking about the condition which you have used. That condition seems to fails at each and every instance. Once the condition will be true then comes the part of Max/Min.
I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Ohh sorry i wrongly put invert condition..a=>a.Percentvalue>=0.5 && a.Percentvalue<=90

Comment: @nitin will this return a LIST<> of Percentvalue of MIN and MAX

Comment: @Nitin or will this return a single value

Answer (score 1):

```
var maximums = table.Where(x => x.PercentValue == table.Where(a=>a.PercentValue>=0.5 && a.PercentValue<=90 ).Max(y => y.PercentValue));
var minimums = table.Where(x => x.PercentValue == table.Where(a=>a.PercentValue>=0.5 && a.PercentValue<=90 ).Min(y => y.PercentValue));
var rnd = new Random();
var result = maximums.Union(minimums).OrderBy(id => rnd.Next()).Take(20).ToList();
```